# How do i block USB devices based on device class in Linux

Tags: linux, rhel, usb, access-control

`Problem Statement`

In windows server to provide access to USB devices are managed by GFI EndpointSecurity. Is there any open source tool in Linux which can do the same job. 
I want to block USB devices based on device class. I am looking for a `add-on` or `some set of commands`. I want to install the add-on in Linux server and provide access to client systems based on groups.

`tried out`

I have seen post on 'how to block usb storage devices in linux'. [as shown here](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/08/how-to-disable-and-enable-usb-device-in-linux/).

Comment: I guess you could write custom udev rules that accept or reject certain USB devices based on their class/IDs. I don't know if there's a readymade tool for that though.

Comment: Since, on linux, one can set the default mount permissions to nodev,noexec,nosuid,  there is little demand for such blocking.  As @MartinvonWittich says, custom udev rules would do it.

Answer (score 3):

Blocking USB devices based on various attributes (including the class and/or protocol) or even conditions (e.g. "if this device is connected, then" or "if the local time is in this range, then") is possible using [USBGuard](https://github.com/dkopecek/usbguard).

Here's an example rule that blocks a specific class of USB devices:

```
block with-interface one-of { 02:*:* e0:*:* }
```

The rule will block any USB device that contains an interface from either the Wireless class (`02:XX:XX`) or Communications class (`e0:XX:XX`).

HW vendors don't always follow the USB class and protocol hierarchy and use a vendor specific class instead (`FF:00:00`) and implement the functionality in a vendor-specific driver instead. In that case, you'll have to block the device based on different attributes.